# Cannot run spark submit in standalone spark cluster

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-standalone

I am working with the following docker-compose image to build a spark standalone cluster:

```
---
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# -- Docs: https://github.com/cluster-apps-on-docker/spark-standalone-cluster-on-docker --
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
version: "3.6"
volumes:
  shared-workspace:
    name: "hadoop-distributed-file-system"
    driver: local
services:
  jupyterlab:
    image: andreper/jupyterlab:3.0.0-spark-3.0.0
    container_name: jupyterlab
    ports:
      - 8888:8888
      - 4040:4040
    volumes:
      - shared-workspace:/opt/workspace
  spark-master:
    image: andreper/spark-master:3.0.0
    container_name: spark-master
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
      - 7077:7077
    volumes:
      - shared-workspace:/opt/workspace
  spark-worker-1:
    image: andreper/spark-worker:3.0.0
    container_name: spark-worker-1
    environment:
      - SPARK_WORKER_CORES=1
      - SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=512m
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    volumes:
      - shared-workspace:/opt/workspace
    depends_on:
      - spark-master
  spark-worker-2:
    image: andreper/spark-worker:3.0.0
    container_name: spark-worker-2
    environment:
      - SPARK_WORKER_CORES=1
      - SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=512m
    ports:
      - 8082:8081
    volumes:
      - shared-workspace:/opt/workspace
    depends_on:
      - spark-master
```

I followed this guide: https://towardsdatascience.com/apache-spark-cluster-on-docker-ft-a-juyterlab-interface-418383c95445.

Here can be found the Github repo: https://github.com/cluster-apps-on-docker/spark-standalone-cluster-on-docker

I can run the cluster and I can run code inside of the jupyter container, connecting to the master spark node without problems.

The problem starts when I want to run the spark code with spark submit. I really cannot understand how the cluster works. When I run inside the Jupyter container, I can quickly see where the scripts I create are, but I can't find them in the spark master container. If I check the docker-compose.yml, the volumes indicates that the folder where the scripts are stored is:

```
 volumes:
      - shared-workspace:/opt/workspace
```

But I cannot find this folder in any of the spark containers.

When I run, spark submit, I run it once I have executed inside of the Jupyter container. In the Jupyter container I have all the scripts that I am working with, but I have the doubt when I write the following command: `spark submit --master spark:// spark-master:7077 <PATH to my python script>`, the path of the python script, is the path where the script in Jupyter container or spark master container?

I can run the `spark submit` command without specifying the master, then it runs locally, and it runs without problems inside of the Jupyter container.

This is the python code I am executing:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from os.path import expanduser, join, abspath

sparkConf = SparkConf()
sparkConf.setMaster("spark://spark-master:7077")
sparkConf.setAppName("pyspark-4")
sparkConf.set("spark.executor.memory", "2g")
sparkConf.set("spark.driver.memory", "2g")
sparkConf.set("spark.executor.cores", "1")
sparkConf.set("spark.driver.cores", "1")
sparkConf.set("spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled", "false")
sparkConf.set("spark.shuffle.service.enabled", "false")
sparkConf.set("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", warehouse_location)
spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=sparkConf).getOrCreate()
sc = spark.sparkContext

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (1, "foo"),  # create your data here, be consistent in the types.
        (2, "bar"),
    ],
    ["id", "label"],  # add your column names here
)
print(df.show())
```

But when I specify the `master= --master spark:// spark-master: 7077`, and specifying the path where the script lives in the jupyter container:

```
spark-submit --master spark://spark-master:7077 test.py
```

ant this are the logs I receive:

```
21/06/06 21:32:04 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
21/06/06 21:32:08 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 3.0.0
21/06/06 21:32:09 INFO ResourceUtils: ==============================================================
21/06/06 21:32:09 INFO ResourceUtils: Resources for spark.driver:

21/06/06 21:32:09 INFO ResourceUtils: ==============================================================
21/06/06 21:32:09 INFO SparkContext: Submitted application: pyspark-4
21/06/06 21:32:09 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: root
21/06/06 21:32:09 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: root
21/06/06 21:32:09 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
21/06/06 21:32:09 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
21/06/06 21:32:09 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(root); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(root); groups with modify permissions: Set()
21/06/06 21:32:12 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 45627.
21/06/06 21:32:12 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
21/06/06 21:32:13 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
21/06/06 21:32:13 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Using org.apache.spark.storage.DefaultTopologyMapper for getting topology information
21/06/06 21:32:13 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: BlockManagerMasterEndpoint up
21/06/06 21:32:13 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMasterHeartbeat
21/06/06 21:32:13 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /tmp/blockmgr-5a81855c-3160-49a5-b9f9-9cdfe6e5ca62
21/06/06 21:32:14 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 366.3 MiB
21/06/06 21:32:14 INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
21/06/06 21:32:16 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
21/06/06 21:32:16 INFO SparkUI: Bound SparkUI to 0.0.0.0, and started at http://3b232f9ed93b:4040
21/06/06 21:32:19 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Connecting to master spark://spark-master:7077...
21/06/06 21:32:20 INFO TransportClientFactory: Successfully created connection to spark-master/172.21.0.5:7077 after 284 ms (0 ms spent in bootstraps)
21/06/06 21:32:23 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Connected to Spark cluster with app ID app-20210606213223-0000
21/06/06 21:32:23 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 46539.
21/06/06 21:32:23 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 3b232f9ed93b:46539
21/06/06 21:32:23 INFO BlockManager: Using org.apache.spark.storage.RandomBlockReplicationPolicy for block replication policy
21/06/06 21:32:23 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registering BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, 3b232f9ed93b, 46539, None)
21/06/06 21:32:23 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager 3b232f9ed93b:46539 with 366.3 MiB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, 3b232f9ed93b, 46539, None)
21/06/06 21:32:23 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, 3b232f9ed93b, 46539, None)
21/06/06 21:32:23 INFO BlockManager: Initialized BlockManager: BlockManagerId(driver, 3b232f9ed93b, 46539, None)
21/06/06 21:32:25 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: SchedulerBackend is ready for scheduling beginning after reached minRegisteredResourcesRatio: 0.0
21/06/06 21:32:29 INFO SharedState: Setting hive.metastore.warehouse.dir ('null') to the value of spark.sql.warehouse.dir ('/opt/workspace/spark-warehouse').
21/06/06 21:32:29 INFO SharedState: Warehouse path is '/opt/workspace/spark-warehouse'.
ESTOY AQUI¿¿
21/06/06 21:33:09 INFO CodeGenerator: Code generated in 1925.0009 ms
21/06/06 21:33:09 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: showString at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0
21/06/06 21:33:09 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 0 (showString at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0) with 1 output partitions
21/06/06 21:33:09 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 0 (showString at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0)
21/06/06 21:33:09 INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()
21/06/06 21:33:09 INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
21/06/06 21:33:10 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 0 (MapPartitionsRDD[6] at showString at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0), which has no missing parents
21/06/06 21:33:10 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0 stored as values in memory (estimated size 11.3 KiB, free 366.3 MiB)
21/06/06 21:33:11 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 5.9 KiB, free 366.3 MiB)
21/06/06 21:33:11 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on 3b232f9ed93b:46539 (size: 5.9 KiB, free: 366.3 MiB)
21/06/06 21:33:11 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 0 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:1200
21/06/06 21:33:11 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 1 missing tasks from ResultStage 0 (MapPartitionsRDD[6] at showString at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0) (first 15 tasks are for partitions Vector(0))
21/06/06 21:33:11 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 0.0 with 1 tasks
21/06/06 21:33:26 WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
21/06/06 21:33:41 WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
21/06/06 21:33:56 WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
21/06/06 21:34:11 WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
21/06/06 21:34:26 WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
```

When I execute the same code, inside of a jupyter notebook, it works without problems.

It is because the path that I have to indicate for the script, is the path where the script lives in the spark-master node? or I am confounding things here

Comment: If you go to Spark master UI, do you have any executor currently running?

Comment: Note that initiail job has not accepted resources. How much available RAM do you have in your dockers? Note you are requiring 2GB for both driver and executors.

Comment: Oh, just noticed- `SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=512m`, so there's your answer..

Answer (score 0):

I use

```
docker pull bitnami/spark
```

https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/spark